# Java EE workflow web services

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, workflow

There is any practical book or tutorial that explain to use Java EE with workflow and web services, if the reference you post contain the source code of the entire case study, it will be an asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into JBoss jBPM project: http://www.jboss.org/jbpm, its BPMN 2.0 compilant and has pretty good documentation